# Whats the variable name (DropDown List)

Tags: php, mysql

i am new to php and i have run into some problems. I am trying to retrieve data from the database and i have managed to do it and display it as dropdown list, however, i am unable to insert it back to the database with the variable i have selected. Please help. May i know what is the variable that i have post to the next page? (which is the processstaffb.php)

```
<form action="processstaffb.php" method="post">
 <table id="t01">    
  <td width="1%">
  <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli(spf, dbuser, dbpw, db);
    $sql="Select sbranch_name from branches";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
       echo "<select name='sbranch_name'>";
       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['sbranch_name'] . "'>" .$row['sbranch_name'] . "</option>";
        }
       echo "</select>";
      }  
     $mysqli->close();
    ?>
   </td>
```

This is the code at processstaffb.php

```
    if (!empty($_POST['sbranch_name'])) 
{
   $sbranch_name =$_POST["$sbranch_name"];
   echo "if pass";
   echo "$sbranch_name";
}
else 
{ 
   $sbranch_name = null;
   echo '<p><font color="red">You forgot to enter the branch of the officer!</font></p>';
   echo "if fail";
   echo "$sbranch_name";
}
```

Comment: put `var_dump($_POST)` on your processtaffb.php page and take a look for yourself

Comment: youll want to provide the code for the 2nd page in order to provide help

Comment: please don't repost.

Comment: @JohnKane i have posted the code for the processstaffb

Answer (score 2):

Because you gave your `select` the name `"sbranch_name"` you can access the value of the selected option in *processstaffb.php* with `$_POST['sbranch_name']`.

Because you are planning to insert the values in your database, this is a good point to learn about [PDO prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [MySQLi prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: they can also use mysqli with a prepared statement, seeing they're using the mysql api.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Thanks for the hint, added the docu for it aswell.

Comment: you're welcome and cheers on the edit. Btw, what they posted is a repost. I'd take a look at the duplicate for it.